# Can $x^n$ be uniformly approximated by the combination of $x^{k^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory

> For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ , can $x^n$ be uniformly approximated by the linear combination of $\left(x^{k^2}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ ?

In order to facilitate a solution, we might as well try to approximate $x^n$ only on $[0,1]$ first.

**My Attempt**

At the beginning I wanted to prove that every continuous function can be uniformly approximated by the linear combination of $(x^{k^2})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $[0,1]$. But from [a theorem of Müntz](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.3570.pdf), I found this idea wrong.

Considering that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, $\Pi=\text{span}\{x^{k^2}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ isn't a dense subset of $C[0,1]$
.

On the other hand, $\tilde\Pi=\text{span}\{x^{k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a dense subset of $C[0,1]$. And if $x^n$ can be approximated, it yields that every polynomial can be approximated by the linear combination of $(x^{k^2})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Does this imply that not all the $x^n$ can be uniformly approximated by the linear combination of $(x^{k^2})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$? But actually I was asked to prove that it's right.

Any helps? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, there exist some $x^n$ such that it cannot be approximated uniformy by linear combinations of the $x^{k^2}$. Else, the $x^{k^2}$ would be dense in the polynomials, and hence dense in $C[0,1]$., which contradicts Müntz theorem. But I don't know what is the smallest $n$ such that $x^n$ cannot be approximated...

Comment: Reconsidering the proof, I think that no one of the $x^n$, where $n$ is not a perfect square, can be approximated by linear combinations of the $x^{k^2}$.

Comment: @DLeMeur Oh that's amazing. Can you give me some hints to prove that?

Comment: See the pages 3,4 of the article you sent : https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.3570.pdf . You make the calculation of the minimum error of a $L^2$ approximation with classical formulas, and there is a trick in this peticular case, that makes the $L^2$ approximations and $C[0,1]$ approximations very similar.

Comment: @DLeMeur I guess you mean that $E(x^q,\Pi)\ge E(x^q,\Pi)_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2q+1}} \prod_{k=0}^\infty \frac{|q-k^2|}{q+k^2+1}$ which is a fixed positive number for $q$ not a perfect square. Thanks very much for your help.